# How to grep some string(IP:port) from text file and print in screen using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

test.txt:

```
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.1:678 blah blah.com2
this is the https ip : 1.1.1.2:654 blah blah.com2
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 blah blah.com2
the sever this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 blah blah.com2
```

From the above text file, I want to grep only IP addresses:port number that starts with "http ip" as shown below.

It should print :

```
1.1.1.1:678
1.1.1.4:456
```

I have tried with following python code:

```
import re
file_open = open("test.txt", 'r')

for i in file_open:
    if re.findall(".*http(.*)",i):
        print i[0]
```

If I run the above python code, it prints :

```
2
2
2
```

Any idea to fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
file_open = open("test.txt", 'r')

for i in file_open:
    result = re.match('.*(http ip : )([0-9:.]+)', i)
    if result:
        print result.group(2)
```

For test.txt with these contents

```
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.1:678 blah blah.com2
this is the https ip : 1.1.1.2:654 blah blah.com2
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 blah blah.com2
the sever this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 blah blah.com2
```

This is the output:

```
1.1.1.1:678
1.1.1.4:456
1.1.1.4:456
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Its works. Actually I want grep IP that starts with "http ip :". Any idea on this please?

Comment: I changed it to include the "http ip :". Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I dont want to print "http ip : IP:port". Actually I wanted to grep the string(IP:port), that starts with "http ip:". For example, If I have a line "this is the https ip : 2.1.1.1:678 blah blah.com2", It should not print this IP. I hope now I am clear in my question. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: I changed it to use a regular expression to handle the "http ip :".

Comment: Actually its prints nothing. I mean I am NOT getting any output. Could you please check once?

Comment: Sorry about that. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94748/discussion-between-david-cullen-and-kumar).

Comment: But my text file contents should be like :
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.1:678 etc.com2
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.2:654 etc.com2

If I change the text file as below:
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.1:678 etc.com2
this is the https ip : 1.1.1.2:654 etc.com2
this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 etc.com2
the sever this is the http ip : 1.1.1.4:456 blah blah.com2
I am getting following error:
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python test.py
1.1.1.1:678
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
if 2 == len(result.groups()):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: @Davis Cullen Sorry for above zigzag format of texts... I posted my errror details in chat in correct format.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Its perfectly works now.